# Ionic 3 How to know if GPS is enable

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation

I'm using Ionic 3 and in a page in need to follow the position of the user ( only latitude and longitude ). How can I know if GPS is enable or not and how can I know if the user disable GPS through the android control panel ?

This is my code :

```
this.geolocation.watchPosition({enableHighAccuracy : true,maximumAge:0}).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined).subscribe((position: Geoposition)=>{
    this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;  
});
```

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-check-if-geolocation-is-enable-or-not-with-native-gps/88762

Comment: Yes I already saw this post but that is not working correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use android permissions https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/

```
this.geolocation.watchPosition({enableHighAccuracy : true,maximumAge:0}).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined).subscribe((position: Geoposition)=>{
   this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).then(
     result => console.log('Has permission?',result.hasPermission),
     err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
   );
   this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
   this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;  
});
```